# How to obtain the model behind a simulator?

Tags: time-series, modeling, simulation

I am looking for an useful statistical approach or analysis tool in order to understand the data obtained from an aeroelastic simulator of wind turbine dynamics.

In this case, the simulation provides data about the forces that a structure has to resist against the wind. Imagine a large structure such as a wind turbine which its base is loaded (with forces and moments) at each time step. This structural loads depend on the loads of previous instances of time (autocorrelated) and more variables such as wind intensity, angle of the attack, lift coefficients, relative speed, blade deflection of different sections of different blades, and other variables. The dataset is a time series of 12000 observations with 195 variables with many dependencies among them but some can be pointed out by an expert aeronautical engineer. She believes that some dependencies are non linear.

**The main goal is to quantify the grade of dependency, in other words, what variables influence more the response variable (loads at the tower base)**. Later on I would also like to estimate the model using a data set from a different structure and see whether more influence variable are the same. I expect to see the same group of variables because the simulator’s algorithm is always the same.

I thought about some approaches but I want to know your experiences in similar problems.
- Generalized Linear Model or design of experiments, I have experience using them but I don't know how to capture the autocorrelation and the non-linearity.
- Multivariate Time series models, I do not have too much experience, but I believe they can capture the dependencies.
- What about more flexible and opaque models such as neural networks.

I am a recent graduate statistician and we hardly seen such complex problems during the degree. However, I am very confident with R and I'd love to know a good approach in order to start my research at CRAN and Wikipedia. My starting point is the [Time Series View Task](http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/web/views/TimeSeries.html).

Comment: If your goal is to quantify parameter dependencies have you considered a sensitivity analysis? This [report](http://www.nrel.gov/docs/fy08osti/41958.pdf) may be of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem properly, but if your goal is to model simulator, you've to remember that it's based on laws of motion and energy, which are well defined mathematical equations, but just that the specific model you're studying is very complex and has too many variables. My suggestion would be to build model based on mechanics [aerodynamics and structural mechanics], rather than simply build a statistical/heuristic model. You may have to take help of CAE (computational aided engineering) expert, to model such things. Apart from that, a very good and basic starting point would be to start with dimensional analysis taught in elementary physics courses and text books, to find out relationship between different variables.

http://physics.about.com/od/classroomphysics/qt/quickunits.htm

Comment: Velcome to our site!